# How to replace values in a specific column of a matrix within a defined index range in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace

I have the following matrix in MATLAB where the first column contains just ones:
[image: Original Matrix]

How can I replace the values in column 1 (regardless of what the original value is) with a new value (e.g. 99) within a specific index range (e.g. just for rows 9 to 12) to obtain this:

[image: desired result]

If I use the following command I can replace all the 1 in the first column with 99:

```
finalMatrix(finalMatrix(:,1) == 1,1) = 99;
```

To replace just the values in column 1 from index 9 to 12 I tried this

```
finalMatrix(finalMatrix(9:12,1) == 1,1) = 99;
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: just specifying the range to be replace should be all that is needed e.g. for the above `finalMatrix(9:12,1)=99`, testing the value seems unnecessary from my reading of the question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it doesn't work (and it should work anyway even testing the value, since all the values are 1)

Comment: doesn't work thats puzzleing, any error message?? also with testing is possible but in he code above `finalMatrix(9:12,1) == 1` will return the logical array `[1;1;1;1;1]` ...

Comment: To replace all the first column : `finalMatrix(:,1) = 99;` ... and to replace only a selection of rows : `finalMatrix(9:12,1) = 99;`. As @RTL said, you shouldn't need to test the value, specially if they are all equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
finalMatrix(finalMatrix(9:12,1) == 1,1) = 99;
```

you will actually replace the first 4 elements of `finalMatrix`, assuming that the corresponding values in `9:12` were `==1`.  The reason is that Matlab does the following steps:

```
1) generate a 4x1 matrix finalMatrix(9:12,1)
2) figure out which of the four elements is ==1
3) return a boolean array (four elements long) corresponding to those elements
4) perform logical indexing on finalMatrix with these four elements -
   which now reference the first four elements of the first column of finalMatrix
```

You just need

```
finalMatrix(9:12,1) = 99;
```

Or, if you care that the values were 1 to begin with, you could do

```
indx = find(finalMatrix(9:12,1)==1);
finalMatrix(indx+8,1)=1;
```